# How to fix UploadNotAllowed error in Flask when no file is uploaded?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I have a fairly basic Bootstrap form which includes a file upload, which on the backend is handled through Python, Flask, Flask-Uploads and inserted into a MongoDB database. When I test submitting the form without a file included in the fields, I get an UploadNotAllowed error from Flask-Uploads, even though I have a failsafe in my code to default to a static image if no file is included.

I have included an if statement in my Python code which, as far as I can tell, should include a default image in the 'insert_one' function which moves data from the form to the database, but it's almost as if that statement is being ignored when I run the code.

Here are the relevant sections of my Python code (some sections removed for brevity):

```
import os, datafunctions
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, session, redirect, flash
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo, pymongo
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
# Adding flask_uploads to allow custom recipe images to be uploaded by users
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, IMAGES

# Flask_uploads configuration for image uploads
images = UploadSet('images', IMAGES)
app.config['UPLOADED_IMAGES_DEST'] = 'static/images/uploads'
configure_uploads(app, images)

# Insert recipe to database
@app.route('/insert_recipe', methods=['POST'])
def insert_recipe():
    # Upload image to uploads folder and generate filepath
if 'image' in request.files:
    filename = images.save(request.files['image'])
    filepath = '../static/images/uploads/' + filename
else:
    filepath = '../static/images/default.jpg'
# Submits to temp_recipes collection to allow for preview without displaying in recipe-results
temp_recipes = mongo.db.temp_recipes
new_recipe = temp_recipes.insert_one(
    {
    'image': filepath,
    }
)
```

And the file input field in my Bootstrap form:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFileAddon01">Upload</span>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="image" name="image" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="image">Choose file</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try and submit the form without including an image, I get the following error:

flask_uploads.UploadNotAllowed

When I try and submit the form and do include the image, it submits perfectly and inserts all the data I would expect into the MongoDB database.

Answer (score 2):

Figured this one out - turns out I needed to use the following in my if statement:

```
if 'image' in request.form:
```

Rather than:

```
if 'image' in request.files:
```

Such a small thing, such a big headache!